# Mysql gem for Snow Leopard Install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to get the mysql gem installed with a fresh install of Snow Leopard.

I got mysql 5.1 x86 installed from mysql site, and have tried install the mysql gem using this command.

> sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

getting no love.

this is my error.

> gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin10.0.0
>   -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward
>   -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_SSL_SET -DHAVE_MYSQL_H  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -g -Os -arch i386 -fno-common   -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL -fno-common -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1 -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common  -o mysql.o -c mysql.c
>
> mysql.c: In function ‘escape_string’:
>
> mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>
> mysql.c:290: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
>
> mysql.c: In function ‘real_escape_string’:
>
> mysql.c:434: error: lvalue required as left operand
>   of assignment
>
> mysql.c:434: error:
>   lvalue required as left operand of
>   assignment
>
> make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1

Anyone having similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALl good,

installed 64 bit mysql, and worked ok.

Comment: Step by-step instructions can be found here:
http://www.icoretech.org/2009/08/install-mysql-and-mysql-ruby-gem-on-snow-leopard-64-bit/

Comment: Did you install prepackaged MySQL x86_64 binary or did you compile your own.  I am running into the same exact error that you posted.

Comment: Yep compiled it myself, the 64 bit version